Update to 2.4.7 give Symfony error
Trying to update site from 2.4.6-p6 to 2.4.7 or 2.4.7-p1
:composer.phar require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.7 --no-update
:composer.phar update
Get the following err:
*"Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - symfony/process[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.10] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.2.21) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.10.0, ..., 3.12.0] require symfony/process ^4.4||^5.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.40].
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.7.0, ..., 3.9.0] require symfony/process ^4.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: symfony/process[2.0.4, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.40, v6.0.0, ..., v6.4.8, v7.0.0, ..., v7.1.1].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7 requires symfony/process ^6.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v6.4.0, ..., v6.4.8].
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, ..., 3.6.1] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.2.21) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.7].
    - Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, ..., 3.12.0].
Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions."*

It seems that Symfony has v4.4 loaded & I can't seem to persuade it to load v6.4.
I have tried using the option -W but still the same error.
 
If I run the newer version of the command
composer.phar require-commerce magento/product-community-edition=2.4.7-p1 --no-update
composer.phar update
I get a different  error:

*"PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Magento\ComposerRootUpdatePlugin\Plugin\Commands\MageRootRequireCommand::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output) must be compatible with Composer\Command\RequireCommand::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output): int in /var/www/vhosts/**************/vendor/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/Plugin/Commands/MageRootRequireCommand.php on line 151
Fatal error: Declaration of Magento\ComposerRootUpdatePlugin\Plugin\Commands\MageRootRequireCommand::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output) must be compatible with Composer\Command\RequireCommand::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output): int in /var/www/vhosts/****************/vendor/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/Plugin/Commands/MageRootRequireCommand.php on line 151"*

I have tried running it with PHP 8, 8.1 & 8.2
Thanks for looking

I'm also facing the same issue, how did you resolved it @savan


remember whenever you try to upgrade use -w with composer update
command so it will download the extra dependencies for the core
modules.

composer update -w


This is most likely cause by dev requirements.
Check the require-dev section of the composer.json for the target version:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.7-p1/composer.json
Update your local composer.json's require-dev section:
...
"require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "^2",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7 || ^1.0",
        "dg/bypass-finals": "^1.4",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^3.22",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "^0.8",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^4.7",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.10",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.12",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.9",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0",
        "symfony/finder": "^6.4"
    },
...

In that case the older version of magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework in your composer.json has the problem causing requirement:
"symfony/process": "^4.4",

In composer.json
update version of "symfony/process" to
"symfony/process": "^6.4"


I tried that but then it just complained that another process needed a different version so I changed that, etc etc etc & then I was back to square one as well as it demanding php 5.6..  They way I got round it was to revert from backup the one site that I had managed to upgrade back to 2.4.6, copy the composer.json & paste the whole thing into the site I was having trouble with & this worked but there are a few issues to resolve after the upgrade for instance when I went to change the encryption key the field disappeared when I change it to yes.  The key still changed when I saved .

you will need to do a composer update with the W flag
composer update -W

